# Как вынести метод в другой класс?

Tags: java, android, activity

Есть проект с классом `MainActivity` и соответствующим `layout/activity_main`.

Создаю новый класс `MainFuncProject`.

По кнопке в `MainActivity` должна вызываться процедура `UpdateData()`, которая прописана в `MainFuncProject`.

Подскажите, как такое реализовать?

Comment: можно сделать метод статичным или передать объект класса MainFuncProject и вызвать у нее UpdateData().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты не поверишь, но надо взять представление `MainFuncProject` и дернуть его метод `UpdateData()`.

Добыть инстанс класса можно через синглтон, через интерфейс, обсерверы и кучу других страшных слов. Или просто объявить метод статиком и дать ему все что надо, тогда можно дергать сразу `MainFuncProject.UpdateData()`

Дергать метод можно напрямую, но лучше использовать интерфейсы, по возможности надо избегать тесного связывания классов. Ибо если они тесно связаны, то зачем их разделять?